# Publish LightSwitch Web app locally

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch, setup-deployment

I'm trying to publish a LightSwitch app (web client) to a local computer and local network location.

Unfortunately all the videos I've encountered on-line only show how to deploy the desktop app but not web..

My LightSwitch app is connected to MS SQL server and SQL Server is installed on the same network but not on the local machine.

Here is how far I can get in the LightSwitch publishing wizard:

[image]

Are there any good videos regarding how to deploy web LightSwitch apps locally with visual Studio 2013?

Or a condense example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The missing link is IIS!  Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off-> find 'Internet Information Services' (IIS) and install it. (There are many options, if unsure install everything except FTP Server)

I'd recommend watching a few tutorials about IIS to get you started.

(2) Next step is to download and install Web Deploy v3.5. (Make sure you choose custom install and select ALL options.)

(3a) In Programs and Features you'll need to make sure the 'Management Service' is installed.

(3b) You will need to make sure the 'Web Management Service' service is started and set to start automatically.

(4) Configure IIS for Web Deploy.  (From memory: locate your Default Website in IIS, right click and you'll find a deployment wizard.  Run it to create a deployment settings xml file.  You can import this into the LightSwitch Publish Application Wizard.)

Side note: The User Name field (You've got 'sa') is not the database account, but a system account.

Good luck.